# Configuration service throwing exception with Docker

Tags: java, docker, yaml

Okay so I am learning to work with microservices with `docker`
I got so far very simple services, however when I try to configure my `config-server` with another service I get an exception:

**Exception:**

```
Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://config-server:8888/. Will be trying the next url if available
2021-12-20 20:26:09.425  WARN [currency-exchange,,] 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.context.config.ConfigDataLoader    : Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@72d1ad2e uris = array<String>['http://config-server:8888/'], optional = true, profiles = list['default']]): I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server:8888/currency-exchange/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

**config service properties:**

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/fastaca/CloudConfig/
```

As you can see I am pointing url to a `github` repository.

**Repository:**

```
*currency-exchange.yml*

server:
  port: 8007
```

NOTE: the configuration service image name is `config-server`

**currency-exchange properties:**

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888/
spring.application.name=currency-exchange
spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
config-server:
    image: config-server
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    networks:
      - currency-network
    environment:
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server-microservice:8761/eureka
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/



  currency-exchange-microservice:
    image: currency-exchange-microservice
    networks:
      - currency-network
    depends_on:
      - naming-server-microservice
      - rabbitmq
    environment:
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://naming-server-microservice:8761/eureka
      SPRING.ZIPKIN.BASEURL: http://zipkin-server:9411/
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
      SPRING_ZIPKIN_SENDER_TYPE: rabbit
```

funny thing is I tried running the contrainer a couple of times and one time it was successful, but since then I keep getting that exception.

Still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of docker-compose are you using?

Try deleting the networks section from each compose service and try again. Sometimes adding networks causes the dns to mess up in docker-compose.